# Как написать по новому стандарту es6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport, koa.js

Не могу разобраться в рендеринг, застрял в авторизации, что как пишу я так не рендерит, выходит ошибка

```js
router.post('/', async (ctx) => {
    await passport.authenticate('local', (err, user) => {
        if(user === false){
            console.log(err);
            ctx.render('/', {title: 'Авторизация', message: ctx.body});
        } else {
            const payload = {
                id: user.id,
                displayName: user.displayName,
                email: user.email
            };
            const token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtsecret); //здесь создается JWT
            ctx.body = {user: user.displayName, token: 'JWT ' + token};
            ctx.redirect('/user');
        }
    }) (ctx)
});
```

> (node:6516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Can't set headers after they are
>   sent. (node:6516) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js p rocess with a non-zero exit
>   code.

Использовал данный [пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/324066/)

Comment: `catch` блок добавьте вашему промису.

Comment: @Suvitruf Куда именно?

Comment: В конце `passport.authenticate` добавить `.catch(error => {console.log(error)})`

Comment: @Suvitruf Я получил в ответ, Если я правильно понял https://jsfiddle.net/hollanditkzn/o07h1e1y/, то я получил ошибку TypeError: passport.authenticate(...).catch is not a function

Comment: Ваш код не готов к переходу на async-await. Сначала нужно промисифицировать его.

Comment: А как это сделать? then() и catch(). Просто не совсем понятно для меня как для новичка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот правильный ответ

```js
router.post('/', async (ctx) => {
    await passport.authenticate('local', async(err, user) => {
        if(user === false){
            await ctx.render('login', {title: 'Авторизация', message: 'Неверный логин или пароль'});
        } else {
            console.log(user);
            const payload = {
                id: user.id,
                username: user.username,
            };
            const token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtsecret); //здесь создается JWT
            ctx.body = {user: user.username, token: 'JWT ' + token};
            console.log(ctx.body);
            ctx.redirect('/user');
        }
    }) (ctx)
});
```